# How can I use ucharclasses to change the font for a special script and then restore to what it was before?

Tags: fontspec, ucharclasses

I would like to change the font in XeLaTeX when I enter a new Unicode block with a certain Script (e.g. Devanagari for Hindi languages). The `ucharclasses` package seems to do exactly that.

However, when I leave the place where the different script is used and go back to what I had before (e.g. latin script) I loose the formatting (e.g. boldface) and the font size.

To illustrate, try this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,DIV12,BCOR8.25mm,twoside,parskip=half]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[Devanagari]{ucharclasses}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Liberation Serif}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Liberation Sans}
\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text]{Liberation Mono}
\newfontfamily\hindifont{Siddhanta}
\setTransitionsFor{Devanagari}{\hindifont}{\rm}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A latin script section}
Some latin script
\section{Devanagari: ताजा धनिया के साथ अनायास and so on}
A mixture \textbf{ of normal text and ताजा धनिया के साथ अनायास Devanagari script} in bold
\section{Some more latin script}
Some latin script
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image: Script changes]

The `\setTransitionTo` correctly picks up the Devanagari script and changes the font to Siddhanta. However, when I come back to latin script, the boldface is gone and the fontsize is increased. The table of contents line shows the same problem.

N.B. `\setTransitionsFor{...}{...}{...}` is what the documentation describes as `\setTransitions`. The doc seems to be wrong.

Comment: I don't know if this will solve your problem (and can't test right now, hence not an answer), but you should not use `{\bf text}`. Use `\textbf{text}` instead. For reasons as to why, see the `l2tabu` package.

Comment: @whlt3 Thanks for your advice. I've changed the question to use `\textbf` but that doesn't help. I also added some text to the section title to show the same problem appearing in the table of contents.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try something like this (I used the ^^-notation because I don't have an utf8-editor here):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,DIV12,BCOR8.25mm,twoside,parskip=half]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[Devanagari]{ucharclasses}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\hindifont{Arial Unicode MS}
\makeatletter
\setTransitionsFor{Devanagari}%
 {\let\curfamily\f@family\let\curshape\f@shape\let\curseries\f@series\hindifont}
 {\fontfamily{\curfamily}\fontshape{\curshape}\fontseries{\curseries}\selectfont}
\makeatother

\begin{document} \tableofcontents \section{A latin script section} Some latin script

\section{Devanagari: ^^^^0908 ^^^^0909 and so on} A mixture \textbf{ of normal text and ^^^^0908 ^^^^0909 Devanagari script} in bold
\section{Some more latin script} Some latin script

\end{document}
```

Comment: I bow my head and am deeply impressed. Works like a charm!

Comment: Would you please add some explanation as to what you did here, for us who are font impaired?

Comment: @Yiannis: I simply stored the description of the actual font before switching to `\hindifont` and then called this font when quiting the devanangari block.

Comment: I think this actually doesn't work for mixtures of scripts, where you go from latin to script1 then to script2 and then back to latin. This can happen in Japanese, for example, that can go from kanji to katagana to hiragana and even latin script.

Comment: There is one additional caveat! When I use the non-latin script in the section title and the last latin character before the non-latin script is a `/` you need to add a `\relax ` to make it work, e.g.: `\section{Devanagari /\relax भारी धनिया संकट}`. Otherwise, Ulrike's trick throws an error.

Comment: And one more: In my example, I used `\usepackage[Devanagari]{ucharclasses}`. This restricts the processing of `ucharclasses` to the Devanagari script, which helps with processing time as `ucharclasses` is incredibly slow. However, as a consequence, the detection of the end of the Devanagari script can then fail. Taking out the option helps - and makes the usage of the `\relax` as described above unnecessary.

Comment: @kongo09: 1. The docu doesn't say it explicitly but as far as I can see the transition commands are applied only at "boundary chars". That means things like "a^^^^0908" or "/^^^^0908" will not work. There must be a space or a \relax or a brace (a{^^^^0908}) between the scripts. 2. If more than one script is involved and you nest them a lot restoring the "correct" font can be difficult to do with such a command. In this cases grouping with braces (latin {^^^^0908} latin) may give better results (with braces it is not necessary to restore the font, simply switch to `\hindifont` at the start).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer So how would I use braces automatically? They would have to be escaped somehow when I put them into the command braces, right?

Comment: @kongo09: Use `\bgroup` and `\egroup` (macro form of braces); or `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` (low level grouping).

Comment: This is generally working for me, but I find that the COLOR of the text is not being preserved. I tried the following

Comment: I am losing the current color:
\setTransitionsFor{LatinSupplement}%
 {\colorlet{currentcolor}{.}\let\curfamily\f@family\let\curshape\f@shape\let\curseries\f@series\JapSubstFont\color{currentcolor}}
 {\fontfamily{\curfamily}\fontshape{\curshape}\fontseries{\curseries}\selectfont}
for example doesnt work. the color of the text is always black..

Answer (score 6):

I think it's easy:

```
\def\ResetTransitionTo#1{%
  \XeTeXinterchartoks 255 \csname#1Class\endcsname{\relax}}
\setTransitionsFor{Devanagari}
  {\begingroup\ResetTransitionTo{Devanagari}\sethindifont}
  {\endgroup}
```

This is what we do in `xeCJK`. Note that we must reset the `\XeTeXinterchartoks` to make the group balance. It is a place that `ucharclasses` is not very well implemented.

Hmm, spaces between scripts are necessary here. It's very boring to define all transitions for all scripts in the document, if there are many.

Comment: Can you explain how your solution works? What does `\ResetTransitionTo` do? Is it better than a simple `\setTransitionsFor{Devanagari}{\begingroup\sethindifont}{\endgroup}`?

Comment: Note that the word boundary class currently has the number 4095 (since 2016) instead of 255.