# How to use cyrillic/russian with sciposter?

Tags: fonts, cyrillic, posters, russian, sciposter

I have used `sciposter` before for making posters in English and I am very satisfied. As an example, these are the first few lines in the file:

```
\documentclass{sciposter}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx,url}
\usepackage[english]{babel}   

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newtheorem{Def}{Definition}

\definecolor{BoxCol}{rgb}{0.9,0.35,0.15}

\usepackage{colortbl}                       %Farbe in Tabellen
\usepackage{tabularx} %Zeilenumbruch in Tabelle

\newcommand{\imsize}{0.45\columnwidth}

\title{From voids to quasars - the role of environment in cosmology}
```

And they produce something as nice as this:
[image]

But now I need to make a poster in Cyrillic (could be Bulgarian, but Russian would be just as fine). I tried a few different pieces of advice going around the use of these lines

```
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
```

but these lines always ends with my font being corrupted to this view:

[image]

It seems to me that there is a problem of `sciposter` with cyrillic. Can I correct this somehow? If you know another poster package beside `sciposter`, that works well in Russian/cyrillic, let me know! Tnx

Comment: Have you tried `tikzposter`?

Comment: What happens when you simply try to use `LuaLaTeX` together with an appropriate font? Can you post a whole example, that compiles and shows the issue?

Comment: @OlegLobachev thanks for the hint! I recall that some years ago I had a look at `tikzposter`, but I liked the design of `sciposter` more and I just sticked through the years with the later. Fortunately, I made it work with Ingmar's suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am talking about something like this:

```
\documentclass[portrait]{sciposter}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{sectionbox}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}

\author{N. Nescio and O. Normalverbraucher and S. Else}
\title{Miscellaneous Anomalies \\ A Guide for the Utterly Confused}
\institute{Institut für Tetrapilotomie und Zigeunerische Urbanistik\\}
\leftlogo[1]{{example-image-a}}
\rightlogo[1]{{example-image-b}}
\conference{99. Annual Conference on Impossibilita}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\rule{\textwidth}{2mm}

\begin{multicols}{3}

\begin{abstract} Лорем ипсум долор сит амет, ессе алтерум интерессет нец не, сеа
 те чоро дицерет феугиат. Пер еа оффендит суавитате. Лаореет анциллае инвидунт
 цу хас, ут меис мандамус еос, цум те солет опортере диссентиунт. Не меа игнота
 персиус ехпетендис. Цу вис яуем партем, ест ан амет репримияуе дефинитионес.

Не яуи саперет праесент, не сед цлита тибияуе молестие. Не перицула диссентиет
цомпрехенсам вис, ест ин солум лаореет нолуиссе. Не воцибус перципитур меа.
Ребум ехерци пробатус еа вис, ин елеифенд хендрерит цум, вел не афферт граеци
сигниферумяуе. Тациматес партиендо цум ет, ут вел аутем омиттам. Еу яуо хомеро
интеллегебат.

Сед ан яуас иусто абхорреант. Интегре елаборарет хис ех, сед цаусае инсоленс
ратионибус те. Ет дицунт елигенди цонцлусионемяуе нам. Яуас аццусам еос ут, вел
мунди инимицус ин. Ут аетерно медиоцрем вел, еум яуод елецтрам еу. Нец номинави
тинцидунт цу, ет фабулас яуалисяуе патриояуе еам. Мутат анимал инсоленс еи сед,
долорем анциллае диссентиет ет еос, яуот тантас адверсариум вих ин.

Те ферри вениам опортеат еум. Ипсум аугуе цонституам ад вих. Пер не долоре
темпор, не еум еуисмод сингулис. Вих цу иллуд аццусата демоцритум, меи яуас
облияуе реферрентур ат. Еос ад амет ерипуит репудиандае, дицта лаореет
дигниссим ех мел, тимеам омиттам елаборарет при еа.

Цу рецусабо торяуатос сит. Еи пурто тота муциус ест, усу лорем лудус путант еу.
Но цибо модус лорем про, ад уллум нонумес пер. Афферт муциус инимицус ад сит.
Еи воцент детерруиссет пер, ан ест темпор цонсететур. Еам елит регионе ут, яуо
еиус видит виртуте ад, усу ан реяуе саперет сингулис. Те мунди перицулис
ехпетендис меа, усу те новум рецусабо ассентиор, цибо опортеат еа нам.

Яуем тинцидунт меи ид. Ад хас цоммодо аетерно интерпретарис. Фугит инани бонорум
ет пер, ут оффициис аццусамус цонсететур еос. Вис меис молестие ид, ид меа
долоре цонтентионес, легере яуодси омнесяуе при ид. Амет вирис еи еум, нец еа
мнесарчум нецесситатибус. Не еам персиус нострум торяуатос, но нец ерос дицат.

Еним унум аудире ид мел, тале цивибус суавитате сед ат. Граецо интегре десерунт
ан дуо, нусяуам яуаестио абхорреант но еос. Ерипуит маиестатис сеа ад, цум
мутат десерунт ад, сеа тритани перицула волуптатибус ид. Про моллис ратионибус
посидониум ад, аперири легимус яуи еу, нец легимус бландит ан.

\end{abstract}

\section{Intrinsic method}
\textbf{\scshape Analogon to Circular Polarization}: two scattered coherent electron waves (wave vector transfers: $q_1$, $q_2$, $q_1\perp q_2$ or $q\,'_1$, $q\,'_2$, $q\,'_1\perp q\,'_2$) with a phase difference of $\pi/2$. 

\textbf{\scshape Setup}: see fig. \ref{fig_intrinsic}. 
\begin{itemize}
\item proposed by Nelhiebel \cite{emcd_intrinsic} and used in prior EMCD-measurements\cite{emcd_nature,pd_rubino,pd_hurm},
\item mono crystalline sample as beam splitter, 
\item two Bragg reflexes with phase difference $\pi/2$ in the diffraction plane according to dynamic diffraction theory (see \cite{pd_rubino,pd_hurm}).
\end{itemize}

\textbf{\scshape Deficiencies}:
\begin{itemize}
\item signal low,
\item resolution low (improved by convergent beam technique \cite{mcd_in_eels_2}),
\item long duration of measurement.
\end{itemize}

\textbf{\scshape Needed Improvements}:
\begin{itemize}
\item higher intensity within
\item small specimen area
\item[$\Rightarrow$] focussed beams $\to$ STEM?!
\end{itemize}

\section{Twin Aperture}
\textbf{\scshape Suggestion}: see fig. \ref{fig_twin}
\begin{itemize}
\item twin aperture $\to$ two coherent partial electron waves,
\item condenser lens $\to$ focussing,
\item electrostatic Boersch phase plate (annular electrode) \cite{phaseplate} $\to$ application of phase shift to one partial wave
\end{itemize}

\section{Numerical Calculations}

\textbf{\scshape Intensity Distribution}: $|\psi_{BFP}|^2$, see fig. \ref{fig_linescan}
\begin{eqnarray}
\psi_{BFP}(X,\,Y) &=& \mathrm{J}_1\left(\frac{2\pi R\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}{\lambda f}\right)\frac{\lambda f}{\pi R\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}} \nonumber \\
&& \cdot\left( e^{-\frac{id_1X}{\lambda f}}+e^{-\frac{id_2X}{\lambda f}-i\varphi}\right),\nonumber \\
\Delta\phi(X) &=& \left((d_2-d_1)\frac{X}{\lambda f}+\varphi+\pi\right)\mathrm{mod}(2\pi)-\pi \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{itemize}
\item in sample plane $\equiv$ back focal plane (BFP)
\item influence of phase shift on intensity in BFP
\item what are optimum parameters for $R$, $d_1$, $d_2$ and $\varphi$?
\end{itemize}

\textbf{\scshape Definition}: quality parameter $U$ and weighting function $\Upsilon$:
\begin{eqnarray}
\label{eqn_usignal}
U &=& \frac{\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\Upsilon(X)|\psi_{BFP}(X,\,0)|^2\,\mathrm{d}X}{\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty|\psi_{BFP}(X,\,0)|^2\,\mathrm{d}X} \nonumber\\
\label{eqn_upsilon_1}
\Upsilon(X) &=& 2\,\mathrm{sgn}\left(\Delta\phi(X)\right)\left|\left(\frac{\Delta\phi(X)}{\pi}+\frac{1}{2}\right)\mathrm{mod}\,1-\frac{1}{2}\right| \nonumber\\
\label{eqn_sn}
\mathrm{S/N} &=& \frac{\int\limits_a^b|\psi_{BFP}(X,\,0)|^2\,\mathrm{d}X}{\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty|\psi_{BFP}(X,\,0)|^2\,\mathrm{d}X},\;[a,\,b]: \mathrm{FWHM} \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}

\textbf{\scshape Optimum Parameter Set}: determined by brute-force method
\begin{itemize}
\item numerical calculation: $U$, FWHM and S/N for each parameter set,
\item saving results in MySQL database $\to$ graphical evaluation: fig. \ref{fig_sql_1} and \ref{fig_sql_2}
\item[$\Rightarrow$] \textbf{aperture}: maximum radius and minimum spacing 
%(see fig. \ref{fig_linescan})
\item[$\Rightarrow$] chosen parameters: Radius = $28.5\mu$m, Spacing = $60.7\mu$m, Phase shift = $0.57\pi$
\end{itemize}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c} 
\end{center}
\caption{weighting function $\Upsilon$ (for legend see fig. \ref{fig_linescan})}
\label{fig_upsilon}
\end{figure}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\tiny
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{literature}
\end{multicols}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Adding `\usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{Noto Serif} \setsansfont{Noto Sans}` resolved the problem. The only thing that I don't know now is how to return to the font displayed in my image above, it's not `Noto Serif` from your example. It would be great if you give me a hint, although it's just a minor thing

Comment: What font were you using? LuaLaTeX doesn't restrict you to fonts made for TeX, you can use all .tt.f and .otf fonts.

Comment: You still need to load `\usepackage[russian]{babel}`, for words to be hyphenated.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `polyglossia` package to invoke fonts including Cyrillic letters in the `newcomputermodern` package, which could also be replaced by your fonts including Cyrillic letters. The solution could provide Cyrillic letters with different shapes and line weights. By the way, it's from [the link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/638450/140814).

```
\documentclass[portrait]{sciposter}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{sectionbox}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{russian}
\newfontfamily\russianfont[Script=Cyrillic,Language=Russian,
ItalicFont={NewCM10-Italic.otf}, BoldFont={NewCM10-Bold.otf},
BoldItalicFont={NewCM10-BoldItalic.otf}]{NewCM10-Regular.otf}
\newfontfamily\russianfontsf[Script=Cyrillic,Language=Russian,
ItalicFont={NewCMSans10-Oblique.otf}, BoldFont={NewCMSans10-Bold.otf},
BoldItalicFont={NewCMSans10-BoldOblique.otf}]{NewCMSans10-Regular.otf}
\newfontfamily\russianfonttt[Script=Cyrillic,Language=Russian,
ItalicFont={NewCMMono10-Italic.otf}, BoldFont={NewCMMono10-Bold.otf},
BoldItalicFont={NewCMMono10-BoldOblique.otf}]{NewCMMono10-Regular.otf}

\author{N. Nescio and O. Normalverbraucher and S. Else}
\title{Miscellaneous Anomalies \\ A Guide for the Utterly Confused}
\institute{Institut für Tetrapilotomie und Zigeunerische Urbanistik\\}
\leftlogo[1]{{example-image-a}}
\rightlogo[1]{{example-image-b}}
\conference{99. Annual Conference on Impossibilita}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\rule{\textwidth}{2mm}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{abstract}
\textrussian{
Лорем ипсум долор сит амет, ессе алтерум интерессет нец не, сеа
 те чоро дицерет феугиат. Пер еа оффендит суавитате. Лаореет анциллае инвидунт
 цу хас, ут меис мандамус еос, цум те солет опортере диссентиунт. Не меа игнота
 персиус ехпетендис. Цу вис яуем партем, ест ан амет репримияуе дефинитионес.

Не яуи саперет праесент, не сед цлита тибияуе молестие. Не перицула диссентиет
цомпрехенсам вис, ест ин солум лаореет нолуиссе. Не воцибус перципитур меа.
Ребум ехерци пробатус еа вис, ин елеифенд хендрерит цум, вел не афферт граеци
сигниферумяуе. Тациматес партиендо цум ет, ут вел аутем омиттам. Еу яуо хомеро
интеллегебат.

Сед ан яуас иусто абхорреант. Интегре елаборарет хис ех, сед цаусае инсоленс
ратионибус те. Ет дицунт елигенди цонцлусионемяуе нам. Яуас аццусам еос ут, вел
мунди инимицус ин. Ут аетерно медиоцрем вел, еум яуод елецтрам еу. Нец номинави
тинцидунт цу, ет фабулас яуалисяуе патриояуе еам. Мутат анимал инсоленс еи сед,
долорем анциллае диссентиет ет еос, яуот тантас адверсариум вих ин.

Те ферри вениам опортеат еум. Ипсум аугуе цонституам ад вих. Пер не долоре
темпор, не еум еуисмод сингулис. Вих цу иллуд аццусата демоцритум, меи яуас
облияуе реферрентур ат. Еос ад амет ерипуит репудиандае, дицта лаореет
дигниссим ех мел, тимеам омиттам елаборарет при еа.

Цу рецусабо торяуатос сит. Еи пурто тота муциус ест, усу лорем лудус путант еу.
Но цибо модус лорем про, ад уллум нонумес пер. Афферт муциус инимицус ад сит.
Еи воцент детерруиссет пер, ан ест темпор цонсететур. Еам елит регионе ут, яуо
еиус видит виртуте ад, усу ан реяуе саперет сингулис. Те мунди перицулис
ехпетендис меа, усу те новум рецусабо ассентиор, цибо опортеат еа нам.

Яуем тинцидунт меи ид. Ад хас цоммодо аетерно интерпретарис. Фугит инани бонорум
ет пер, ут оффициис аццусамус цонсететур еос. Вис меис молестие ид, ид меа
долоре цонтентионес, легере яуодси омнесяуе при ид. Амет вирис еи еум, нец еа
мнесарчум нецесситатибус. Не еам персиус нострум торяуатос, но нец ерос дицат.

Еним унум аудире ид мел, тале цивибус суавитате сед ат. Граецо интегре десерунт
ан дуо, нусяуам яуаестио абхорреант но еос. Ерипуит маиестатис сеа ад, цум
мутат десерунт ад, сеа тритани перицула волуптатибус ид. Про моллис ратионибус
посидониум ад, аперири легимус яуи еу, нец легимус бландит ан.
}
\end{abstract}

\section{Intrinsic method}
\textbf{\scshape Analogon to Circular Polarization}: two scattered coherent electron waves (wave vector transfers: $q_1$, $q_2$, $q_1\perp q_2$ or $q\,'_1$, $q\,'_2$, $q\,'_1\perp q\,'_2$) with a phase difference of $\pi/2$. 

\textbf{\scshape Setup}: see fig. \ref{fig_intrinsic}. 
\begin{itemize}
\item proposed by Nelhiebel \cite{emcd_intrinsic} and used in prior EMCD-measurements\cite{emcd_nature,pd_rubino,pd_hurm},
\item mono crystalline sample as beam splitter, 
\item two Bragg reflexes with phase difference $\pi/2$ in the diffraction plane according to dynamic diffraction theory (see \cite{pd_rubino,pd_hurm}).
\end{itemize}

\textbf{\scshape Deficiencies}:
\begin{itemize}
\item signal low,
\item resolution low (improved by convergent beam technique \cite{mcd_in_eels_2}),
\item long duration of measurement.
\end{itemize}

\textbf{\scshape Needed Improvements}:
\begin{itemize}
\item higher intensity within
\item small specimen area
\item[$\Rightarrow$] focussed beams $\to$ STEM?!
\end{itemize}

\section{Twin Aperture}
\textbf{\scshape Suggestion}: see fig. \ref{fig_twin}
\begin{itemize}
\item twin aperture $\to$ two coherent partial electron waves,
\item condenser lens $\to$ focussing,
\item electrostatic Boersch phase plate (annular electrode) \cite{phaseplate} $\to$ application of phase shift to one partial wave
\end{itemize}

\section{Numerical Calculations}

\textbf{\scshape Intensity Distribution}: $|\psi_{BFP}|^2$, see fig. \ref{fig_linescan}
\begin{eqnarray}
\psi_{BFP}(X,\,Y) &=& \mathrm{J}_1\left(\frac{2\pi R\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}{\lambda f}\right)\frac{\lambda f}{\pi R\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}} \nonumber \\
&& \cdot\left( e^{-\frac{id_1X}{\lambda f}}+e^{-\frac{id_2X}{\lambda f}-i\varphi}\right),\nonumber \\
\Delta\phi(X) &=& \left((d_2-d_1)\frac{X}{\lambda f}+\varphi+\pi\right)\mathrm{mod}(2\pi)-\pi \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{itemize}
\item in sample plane $\equiv$ back focal plane (BFP)
\item influence of phase shift on intensity in BFP
\item what are optimum parameters for $R$, $d_1$, $d_2$ and $\varphi$?
\end{itemize}

\textbf{\scshape Definition}: quality parameter $U$ and weighting function $\Upsilon$:
\begin{eqnarray}
\label{eqn_usignal}
U &=& \frac{\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\Upsilon(X)|\psi_{BFP}(X,\,0)|^2\,\mathrm{d}X}{\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty|\psi_{BFP}(X,\,0)|^2\,\mathrm{d}X} \nonumber\\
\label{eqn_upsilon_1}
\Upsilon(X) &=& 2\,\mathrm{sgn}\left(\Delta\phi(X)\right)\left|\left(\frac{\Delta\phi(X)}{\pi}+\frac{1}{2}\right)\mathrm{mod}\,1-\frac{1}{2}\right| \nonumber\\
\label{eqn_sn}
\mathrm{S/N} &=& \frac{\int\limits_a^b|\psi_{BFP}(X,\,0)|^2\,\mathrm{d}X}{\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty|\psi_{BFP}(X,\,0)|^2\,\mathrm{d}X},\;[a,\,b]: \mathrm{FWHM} \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}

\textbf{\scshape Optimum Parameter Set}: determined by brute-force method
\begin{itemize}
\item numerical calculation: $U$, FWHM and S/N for each parameter set,
\item saving results in MySQL database $\to$ graphical evaluation: fig. \ref{fig_sql_1} and \ref{fig_sql_2}
\item[$\Rightarrow$] \textbf{aperture}: maximum radius and minimum spacing 
%(see fig. \ref{fig_linescan})
\item[$\Rightarrow$] chosen parameters: Radius = $28.5\mu$m, Spacing = $60.7\mu$m, Phase shift = $0.57\pi$
\end{itemize}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c} 
\end{center}
\caption{weighting function $\Upsilon$ (for legend see fig. \ref{fig_linescan})}
\label{fig_upsilon}
\end{figure}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\tiny
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{literature}
\end{multicols}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Compile the file with XeLeTeX and you will get

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I guess it would work, but it requires me to tinker a little bit with the used packages, while the answer by Ingmar works more straightforward. Hence I upvote your post, but accept his as an answer :)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the other answers that you are better off using modern fonts and Unicode when you can, and legacy 8-bit formats from last century when you have to.  For a conference poster that you are printing out yourself, there is no reason that you have to.  You’re free to use whatever technology you prefer.

That having been said, the cause of your problem is that `sciposter` sets the font family to `phv` (Postscript Helvetica).  Since this doesn’t support the T2A encoding, you get several error messages similar to

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/phv/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T2A/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 112.
```

That is, since your document class selected a font that doesn’t support the T2A font encoding for Cyrillic, LaTeX substitutes the default font, Computer Modern Roman, in medium weight.  This can at least display the correct language.

To fix this without breaking compatibility with PDFTeX, load a Helvetica clone that does support the T2A encoding, such as [Nimbus Sans 2015](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/nimbus15/doc/nimbus15-doc.pdf).  This works for me:

```
\usepackage{nimbussans}
```

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{sciposter}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx,url}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{nimbussans}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018

\newtheorem{Def}{Definition}

\definecolor{BoxCol}{rgb}{0.9,0.35,0.15}

\usepackage{colortbl}                       %Farbe in Tabellen
\usepackage{tabularx} %Zeilenumbruch in Tabelle

\newcommand{\imsize}{0.45\columnwidth}

\title{From voids to quasars - the role of environment in cosmology} 

\author{N. Nescio and O. Normalverbraucher and S. Else}
\title{Miscellaneous Anomalies \\ A Guide for the Utterly Confused}
\institute{Institut für Tetrapilotomie und Zigeunerische Urbanistik\\}
\leftlogo[1]{{example-image-a}}
\rightlogo[1]{{example-image-b}}
\conference{99. Annual Conference on Impossibilita}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\rule{\textwidth}{2mm}

\begin{multicols}{3}

\begin{abstract} Лорем ипсум долор сит амет, ессе алтерум интерессет нец не, сеа
 те чоро дицерет феугиат. Пер еа оффендит суавитате. Лаореет анциллае инвидунт
 цу хас, ут меис мандамус еос, цум те солет опортере диссентиунт. Не меа игнота
 персиус ехпетендис. Цу вис яуем партем, ест ан амет репримияуе дефинитионес.

Не яуи саперет праесент, не сед цлита тибияуе молестие. Не перицула диссентиет
цомпрехенсам вис, ест ин солум лаореет нолуиссе. Не воцибус перципитур меа.
Ребум ехерци пробатус еа вис, ин елеифенд хендрерит цум, вел не афферт граеци
сигниферумяуе. Тациматес партиендо цум ет, ут вел аутем омиттам. Еу яуо хомеро
интеллегебат.

Сед ан яуас иусто абхорреант. Интегре елаборарет хис ех, сед цаусае инсоленс
ратионибус те. Ет дицунт елигенди цонцлусионемяуе нам. Яуас аццусам еос ут, вел
мунди инимицус ин. Ут аетерно медиоцрем вел, еум яуод елецтрам еу. Нец номинави
тинцидунт цу, ет фабулас яуалисяуе патриояуе еам. Мутат анимал инсоленс еи сед,
долорем анциллае диссентиет ет еос, яуот тантас адверсариум вих ин.

Те ферри вениам опортеат еум. Ипсум аугуе цонституам ад вих. Пер не долоре
темпор, не еум еуисмод сингулис. Вих цу иллуд аццусата демоцритум, меи яуас
облияуе реферрентур ат. Еос ад амет ерипуит репудиандае, дицта лаореет
дигниссим ех мел, тимеам омиттам елаборарет при еа.

Цу рецусабо торяуатос сит. Еи пурто тота муциус ест, усу лорем лудус путант еу.
Но цибо модус лорем про, ад уллум нонумес пер. Афферт муциус инимицус ад сит.
Еи воцент детерруиссет пер, ан ест темпор цонсететур. Еам елит регионе ут, яуо
еиус видит виртуте ад, усу ан реяуе саперет сингулис. Те мунди перицулис
ехпетендис меа, усу те новум рецусабо ассентиор, цибо опортеат еа нам.

Яуем тинцидунт меи ид. Ад хас цоммодо аетерно интерпретарис. Фугит инани бонорум
ет пер, ут оффициис аццусамус цонсететур еос. Вис меис молестие ид, ид меа
долоре цонтентионес, легере яуодси омнесяуе при ид. Амет вирис еи еум, нец еа
мнесарчум нецесситатибус. Не еам персиус нострум торяуатос, но нец ерос дицат.

Еним унум аудире ид мел, тале цивибус суавитате сед ат. Граецо интегре десерунт
ан дуо, нусяуам яуаестио абхорреант но еос. Ерипуит маиестатис сеа ад, цум
мутат десерунт ад, сеа тритани перицула волуптатибус ид. Про моллис ратионибус
посидониум ад, аперири легимус яуи еу, нец легимус бландит ан.

\end{abstract}

\section{Intrinsic method}
\textbf{\scshape Analogon to Circular Polarization}: two scattered coherent electron waves (wave vector transfers: $q_1$, $q_2$, $q_1\perp q_2$ or $q\,'_1$, $q\,'_2$, $q\,'_1\perp q\,'_2$) with a phase difference of $\pi/2$. 

\textbf{\scshape Setup}: see fig. \ref{fig_intrinsic}. 
\begin{itemize}
\item proposed by Nelhiebel \cite{emcd_intrinsic} and used in prior EMCD-measurements\cite{emcd_nature,pd_rubino,pd_hurm},
\item mono crystalline sample as beam splitter, 
\item two Bragg reflexes with phase difference $\pi/2$ in the diffraction plane according to dynamic diffraction theory (see \cite{pd_rubino,pd_hurm}).
\end{itemize}

\textbf{\scshape Deficiencies}:
\begin{itemize}
\item signal low,
\item resolution low (improved by convergent beam technique \cite{mcd_in_eels_2}),
\item long duration of measurement.
\end{itemize}

\textbf{\scshape Needed Improvements}:
\begin{itemize}
\item higher intensity within
\item small specimen area
\item[$\Rightarrow$] focussed beams $\to$ STEM?!
\end{itemize}

\section{Twin Aperture}
\textbf{\scshape Suggestion}: see fig. \ref{fig_twin}
\begin{itemize}
\item twin aperture $\to$ two coherent partial electron waves,
\item condenser lens $\to$ focussing,
\item electrostatic Boersch phase plate (annular electrode) \cite{phaseplate} $\to$ application of phase shift to one partial wave
\end{itemize}

\section{Numerical Calculations}

\textbf{\scshape Intensity Distribution}: $|\psi_{BFP}|^2$, see fig. \ref{fig_linescan}
\begin{eqnarray}
\psi_{BFP}(X,\,Y) &=& \mathrm{J}_1\left(\frac{2\pi R\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}{\lambda f}\right)\frac{\lambda f}{\pi R\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}} \nonumber \\
&& \cdot\left( e^{-\frac{id_1X}{\lambda f}}+e^{-\frac{id_2X}{\lambda f}-i\varphi}\right),\nonumber \\
\Delta\phi(X) &=& \left((d_2-d_1)\frac{X}{\lambda f}+\varphi+\pi\right)\mathrm{mod}(2\pi)-\pi \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{itemize}
\item in sample plane $\equiv$ back focal plane (BFP)
\item influence of phase shift on intensity in BFP
\item what are optimum parameters for $R$, $d_1$, $d_2$ and $\varphi$?
\end{itemize}

\textbf{\scshape Definition}: quality parameter $U$ and weighting function $\Upsilon$:
\begin{eqnarray}
\label{eqn_usignal}
U &=& \frac{\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\Upsilon(X)|\psi_{BFP}(X,\,0)|^2\,\mathrm{d}X}{\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty|\psi_{BFP}(X,\,0)|^2\,\mathrm{d}X} \nonumber\\
\label{eqn_upsilon_1}
\Upsilon(X) &=& 2\,\mathrm{sgn}\left(\Delta\phi(X)\right)\left|\left(\frac{\Delta\phi(X)}{\pi}+\frac{1}{2}\right)\mathrm{mod}\,1-\frac{1}{2}\right| \nonumber\\
\label{eqn_sn}
\mathrm{S/N} &=& \frac{\int\limits_a^b|\psi_{BFP}(X,\,0)|^2\,\mathrm{d}X}{\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty|\psi_{BFP}(X,\,0)|^2\,\mathrm{d}X},\;[a,\,b]: \mathrm{FWHM} \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}

\textbf{\scshape Optimum Parameter Set}: determined by brute-force method
\begin{itemize}
\item numerical calculation: $U$, FWHM and S/N for each parameter set,
\item saving results in MySQL database $\to$ graphical evaluation: fig. \ref{fig_sql_1} and \ref{fig_sql_2}
\item[$\Rightarrow$] \textbf{aperture}: maximum radius and minimum spacing 
%(see fig. \ref{fig_linescan})
\item[$\Rightarrow$] chosen parameters: Radius = $28.5\mu$m, Spacing = $60.7\mu$m, Phase shift = $0.57\pi$
\end{itemize}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c} 
\end{center}
\caption{weighting function $\Upsilon$ (for legend see fig. \ref{fig_linescan})}
\label{fig_upsilon}
\end{figure}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\tiny
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{literature}
\end{multicols}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: Nimbus Sans sample]

In some cases, particularly documents where you must use both PDFTeX and a set of fonts that does not support your supplementary language, you might need to define a substitute font as a workaround.  For example, to use the Noto fonts for Cyrillic in a document without changing any of the fonts for English, you might use:

```
\usepackage{substitutefont}

\substitutefont{T2A}{\familydefault}{NotoSerif-LF}
\substitutefont{T2A}{\sfdefault}{NotoSans-LF}
\substitutefont{T2A}{\ttdefault}{NotoSansMono-TLF}
```